# How to publish JSON data into PubSub and then push to BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I am fetching twitter data in JSON format and I want to push that data(same JSON format) into PubSub topic. I am able to Publish data in Topic, but when I try to push data into `BigQuery`, it stores the data into "`Error record table`"(I have already created `BigQuery` table with proper schema and given `table_id` and `dataset_id` as `credentials`)

Comment: Can you provide more details on the setup that send data from pubsub to BigQuery?

Comment: Also, why not just send the data directly to BigQuery after you read from twitter?

Comment: What's your twitter message structure and what's your model in BigQuery? And how do you store them in BigQuery (can you share your code?).?

Answer (score 0):

Issues could be due to below reasons:

1] Destination table schema and table schema specified  in JSON format is different.

2] Datatype of the column and datatype specfied in JSON format is different.

These corrective measures can be taken:

1] In order to fix schema mismatch issue, please make sure to match the JSON and destination table schema. While creating schema try following these steps which are mentioned in doc[1] that explains how to specify the schema of a BigQuery table.

2] Since there is mismatch in datatype try to make sure that you specify correct datatype.

Consider the below JSON schema:

{"message":"hi","id":65,marks:89.8}

In the above example, where message=string,id=integer,marks=float

So any mismatch in datatype,message will be published in error record table.

References:

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages#metadata-errors-for-streaming-inserts

[3] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubtobigquery